# JS Dictionary to Scala Map

Tags: javascript, scala, dictionary

Hi I need some information about passing a javascript dictionary from JS to scala js function and use it as an immutable map. How do I go about doing this? The example given here http://www.scala-js.org/doc/js-interoperability.html gives me an error scala js object cannot be cast to scala.scalajs.js.Dictionary.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are running?

Comment: Well... First of all... there is nothing like dictionary in JS world. Here JS Objects provide dictionary like functionality. And string representation of these JS objects is called JSON. So... if I am guessing correct then you are looking for JSON to scala map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the implicit conversions defined in `JSConverters` for this to work.  This adds a `toMap` method to `js.Dictionary`.

Try:

```
import scala.scalajs.js.JSConverters._

val myMap: Map[String, Any] = js.Dictionary("foo" -> "foo-value", "bar" -> 34).toMap[String, Any]
```